# extjs 3 SuperBoxSelect tag colors

Tags: javascript, css, extjs, extjs3

I have a SuperBoxSelect  element, populated from  remote store.

I need different color for each tag ( set on rowselect). Color value comes with store.

Now i end up trying with:

```
displayFieldTpl: '<tpl for="."><div class="x-superbox-item" 
style="background:{color};">{text}</div>  </tpl>'
```

However tpl creates its on elements inside the  tag ( which is a list element that has another element inside for the close button / X).

What happens is that it now has colored smaller box inside it and background still has default color.

What i would need is a way to change the list elements own background color not create a new element inside it. But tpl doesn't seem to be good enough for that.
These are not fixed colors - they can be anything later set in the config for each specific tag.

The html for it is:

```
<ul id="ext-gen747">
    <li id="ext-gen1001" class="x-superbox-item x-superbox-item x-superbox-item-hover">
        "TestTag2"
        <a class="x-superbox-item-close" tabindex="0" href="#" id="ext-gen1002"></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define `classField` or `styleField` in combo definition which may come handy in this case.

For example if you have colors as names (eg red, green) you can set `classField` to `color` and define proper styles in css. To use `styleField` you should define calculated field in each record to provide so it returns proper style tag.

You can also override `addItemBox` method.